# bluetooth is disable,unable to pair with any mobile

Tags: bluetooth

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 on compaq v3000 .
Before Few days i am able to use my laptop bluetooth services properly .

But after update and upgrade is not working

when i click on "turn on bluetooth" link ,its turn on but  add new device link ,my old pair mobile device is not shown,and in network  button my Mobile number is not shown ,

when I click on "bluetooth setting"

error shown "Bluetooth is disable " and add new device (+/-) ,visibility button is also disable

now i am not able to connect my mobile with laptop bluetooth.unable to connect the network.

I attached the screen shot also ,please check

http://blogalokmohan.blogspot.in/2013/05/bluetooth-is-disable-error-in-ubuntu.html

Answer (score 1):

I too faced this problem. This worked for me:
First list all the wireless devices using `rfkill list` command.

Then use the command `rfkill unblock <index>` where index is the number of the bluetooth interface.

Eg: My `rfkill list` outputs:

`0: sony-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: sony-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no`

So I run `rfkill unblock 1` and `rfkill unblock 3`. Hope this helps.

Comment: works for my ubuntu 14.04 too, don't know why but it works